# How would i display the total sum in one cout rather than individual ones?

Tags: c++

So i have 98% of my code done, but im coming across an issue where instead of one total sum, i'm getting five individual ones. How would i go about just getting one total? My assignment is getting the total payroll of 5 different employees which are in the form of a text file. 
For reference Text code is:

> 123-45-6789,Linda Smith,50, 10.00, 133-56-7890,Carol
>   Melville,35,12.50, 167-33-4589,Marilyn Lloyd,42,16.00,
>   156-90-5432,Joyce Davis,27,11.25, 195-56-9000,Susan Cook, 49,12.00

This is the actual program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct incomeInfo {
    string id;
    string name;
    int hours;
    double hRate;
    double regPay = 0;
    double otPay = 0;
};


const int ARRAY_SIZE = 25; // Array size 
incomeInfo income[ARRAY_SIZE]; // array variable declaration

void getIncome(incomeInfo[], int&);
void compute(incomeInfo *, int);
void display(incomeInfo[], int);
void summary(incomeInfo[], int);

int main()
{

    incomeInfo income[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int count = 0;                          //Initialize count to 0

    getIncome(income, count);
    compute(income, count);
    display(income, count);
    summary(income, count);
    return 0;
}

void getIncome(incomeInfo income[], int &count)
{

    string name;
    char line[50];                      // Variable to read data


    // Open data File to read data
    ifstream inputFile;
    string fileName;
    int value;

    cout << "Please enter the path name where payroll.txt is located (Check the HW5 folder): ";
    getline(cin, fileName);

    // Open the file
    inputFile.open(fileName.c_str());

    // test if data file opened incorrectly
    if (inputFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "\n\n\tError openning file." << "\n\n\t";
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    else
    {
        while (!inputFile.eof())    //Check end of file
        {
            inputFile.getline(line, 50, ',');       // The data are separated by comma 
            income[count].id = line;
            inputFile.getline(line, 50, ',');
            income[count].name = line;
            inputFile.getline(line, 50, ',');
            income[count].hours = atoi(line);       // Convert string to integer
            inputFile.getline(line, 50, ',');
            income[count].hRate = atof(line);           // Convert string to float

            count++;
        }
    }
    inputFile.close();

    return;
}


void compute(incomeInfo *ptrI, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if (ptrI->hours <= 40)
        {
            ptrI->regPay = ptrI->hours * ptrI->hRate;
            ptrI++;
        }

        else if (ptrI->hours > 40)
        {
            //ptrI->regPay = ptrI->hours * ptrI->hRate;

            ptrI->regPay = 40 * ptrI->hRate;
            ptrI->otPay = (ptrI->hours - 40) * (ptrI->hRate + (ptrI->hRate* .5));
            ptrI++;
        }
    }
    return;
}

void display(incomeInfo income[], int count)
{
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << setw(15) << left << "ID" << setw(16) << "Name";
    cout << left << setw(8) << "Hours" << setw(14) << "Hourly Rate" << setw(14) << "Regular Pay" << setw(14) << "Overtime Pay" << endl;


    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(14) << left << income[i].id << setw(15) << income[i].name;
        cout << right << setw(6) << income[i].hours << setw(12) << income[i].hRate;
        cout << setw(14) << income[i].regPay << setw(14) << income[i].otPay << endl;
    }

    return;
}


void summary(incomeInfo income[], int count)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        cout << endl << endl << "Total payroll amount for the company = " << income[i].regPay + income[i].otPay << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post what you have tried so far. You will find others will be more willing to help you fix that bit of code.

Comment: Add the five separate values together and print the result?